# What is the standard way to render each mesh at their respective locations?

Tags: opengl

I have a single mesh, and I give the vertex-shader a matrix which holds the objects position, scale and rotation. It seems to work.

```
in vec3 position;
uniform mat4 object;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;

void main() {
   gl_Position = proj * view * object * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

What if I have multiple meshes? What is the standard way to approach this? Feed in a different `mat4` for every mesh rendered, or have separate vertex shaders for each mesh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each mesh gets a different object matrix (world transformation matrix).

A common sequence of rendering multiple meshes is :

- Use shader program
- Set the uniforms for Mesh1
- Bind VAO/VBO's for Mesh1
- Draw
- Set uniform for world matrix for Mesh2
- Bind VBO/VAO for Mesh2
- Draw

  ....

Comment: thanks mate, being a newb I still don't fully get VBO/VAO stuff, but I'll go do some more reading :)